# "Stray \1 in program" error in a C++ sort program

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, counting-sort

Here's the code of counting sort I implemented in C++:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

void counting_sort(int [], int, int);

main()
{
    int n,k = 0, a[15];
    cout << "Enter the number of input: ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "\nEnter the elements to be sorted: \n";
    for ( int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        cin >> a[i];
        if(a[i] > k)
        {
            k = a[i];
        }
    }
    counting_sort(a, k, n);
    system("pause");
    //getch();
}

void counting_sort(int a[], int k, int n)
{
    int i, j;
    int b[15], c[100];
    for(i = 0; i <= k; i++)
        c[i] = 0;

    for(j =1; j <= n; j++)
        c[a[j]] = c[a[j]] + 1;

    for(i = 1; i <= k; i++)
        c[i] = c[i] + c[i-1];

    for(j = n; j >= 1; j--)
    {
        b[c[a[j]]] = a[j];
        c[a[j]] = c[a[j]] - 1;
    }
    cout << "\nThe Sorted array is: ";
    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    cout << b[i] << " " ;
}
```

There is an error on compilation that states "Stray \1 in program" in Line 3 Col 1. I tried in on [Dev-C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dev-C%2B%2B) and [Ideone](https://www.ideone.com/). Both show the same error. I also tried copying the code to a new file but in vain. How can I rectify it?

Comment: Don't forget to put `int` as return type for main...

Comment: Sounds like your source file is corrupted.  Try copy and pasting the code to another file and compiling.

Comment: The problem is, that there's an invisible invalid character in your source code. You could inspect the text file with a hex editor, to find where it is exactly.

Comment: We won't be able to reproduce this here so it's not a good SO question. @πάνταῥεῖ has your solution though.

Comment: I tried in Dev C++ .it runs perfectly.you should copy paste your code in another text file then compile.

Comment: paste the ideone code link.

Comment: @JerryGoyal Here is the link to the ideone code http://ideone.com/ALbZbr

Comment: @h8pathak There is indeed something strange at the end of line 3. Remove it and it compiles.

Comment: A canonical is *[Compilation error: stray ‘\302’ in program, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198332/compilation-error-stray-302-in-program-etc?noredirect=1&lq=1)* (though should probably only be used for UTF-8 sequences).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an (hidden) invalid character in your code (line:3) which copied along with your code on http://ideone.com/ALbZbr.

Try editing this code. You will see a red dot (invalid character) on the third line.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std; . <--

void counting_sort(int [], int, int);

main()
{
```

Delete this invalid character and your code will eventually run.

Comment: For this, make all the characters visible. It will show stray character.

Comment: 'make all the characters visible' how one would do this.

Comment: @doptimusprime: Can you elaborate? For example, in what environment? In Dev-C++ or Ideone? Or in some other environment (text editor?)? And exact ***how***?